# Visial basic excel example

Tags: excel, vba

can anyone please do this example for me i`m stuck here for about 2 days and cant do it :( 
I need to make a code which will write numbers in this pyramidal way: 1 121 12321 1234321.. and must be written as example at this picture

[image: scr]

Comment: Is this homework? You can do this with a formula.

Comment: No its for my exam..but i have no clue how to do it :( if you can to help me ill be glad to see the answer,thanks!

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: Mate this is not a homework,this is a question for a exam which i have for 3 days and i can not do it,if you can help please help

Comment: In my honest opinion, the principles are similar whether it's homework or an exam. Happy to help if you [edit] your question with what you've tried. Otherwise, it's my effort, not yours, but this is *your* exam.

Comment: or give me some formula any help will be nice

Comment: Here's a formula that you can drag to create it, but I'll leave you to translate to code: `=IF(MOD(ROW()+COLUMN(),2)=0,MIN(ROW(),COLUMN()),"")`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this in a worksheet code

```
Public Sub MakePyramid()

    Dim r_start As Range
    Set r_start = Range("A1")

    Dim i As Long, j As Long, n As Long

    n = 3 ' Number of layers
    For i = 1 To n
        For j = 1 To i
            r_start.Cells(2 * i - j, j).Value = j
            r_start.Cells(j, 2 * i - j).Value = j
        Next j
    Next i

End Sub
```

Result

[image: pic]

But why?

You need to figure out why this code works in order to prepare for your exam.